# Html Redirect Image to Div ID

Tags: html, css

When i click on

```
<a href="images/full/3.jpg#light">  <!-- redirect to Div id=light" -->
```

the image not display on Div Id=light but in a new page ;
fails to find a solution.

```
<html>

<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!-- scripts -->
<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"      />

<head>
scrollmenu1.light{}
</head>

<body>

<!-- div destination -->
<div id="light"> 
<img src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" height="190px">
</div>

<div class="scrollmenu1">
  <a href="images/full/3.jpg#light">  <!-- redirect to Div id=light" -->
    <img src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" height="190px"> 
    <div class="caption">Caption 1</div>
  </a>

  <a href="images/full/4.jpg">
    <img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" height="190px"> 
    <div class="caption">Caption 2</div>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* sezione diapositive */
.images{
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px auto;
}
.images a{
    margin:0px 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 3px;
    color:white;
}

.images a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}


/* scroll zona 2 */
div.scrollmenu1 {
   background-color: #333;
   overflow: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu1 a {
 display: inline-block;  
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu1 a:hover {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This would be same as pasting images/full/3.jpg#light in your browser

Comment: "_the image not display on Div Id=light_" It is not clear why you thought that would happen - You clicked on a link so you navigate somewhere. What _exactly_ were you expecting to happen when you clicked the link? Just have the image shown in a popup sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

A link is an anchor that takes you to a place or location specified by the address, in this case the address in the href = " ". Sorry if that seems too obvious for you but I feel like I needed to remind you of it for the sake of clarity. With that being said, unless you make your code go to a certain div when you click on a link, it won't just magically do it by itself. You can redirect you page to the div you want by specifying the address in the href attribute of the link you click as in here:

```
<div class="scrollmenu1">
<a href="images/full/3.jpg#light">  <!-- redirect to Div id=light" -->
<img src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" height="190px"> 
<div class="caption">Caption 1</div>
</a>

<a href="#Id-Name-Of-The-Div-You-Want-To-Go-To-On-Click">
<img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" height="190px"> 
<div class="caption">Caption 2</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Notice the difference in the href attribute in your link that I changed. This will redirect you to the div. However, like other have pointed out in their comments, you can't just make the image you clicked on to magically appear in the div you want by just having it in between your "a" tags like that. You need some javascript or other ways for that. By default, links  don't work like that.  Also, doing some research before posting questions is a good practice. It will help you learn things better.I hope that helped

Comment: I have tried to apply what you do with iFrame, where this technique works.
Htm, java scripts aren't my world; development in Delphi/C++ and C#.

Comment: Okay I got you man. But does that mean you were able to fix the problem with my solution??